# How can I transpose and summarize data appropriately in PowerQuery?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm working on achieving the following data transformation/wrangling within Power Query but can't seem to get there on my own.  i have read a lof of different questions and answers on the forum but it seems just a bit beyond my grasp.

1. I have a table which has the ticker of a specific currency in the first column.
2. There is a second column with the date and time when a certain event, related to that specific currency, happens.  This second column is basically the different 5-minute intervals which exist on any given day.
3. Finally there is a third column which describes the magnitude of the event.

[The table therefore looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N064p.png)

What I would like to do in power Query is transpose the uniques name of the currencies as the first row of a new table.  The first column of this table would be the largest time interval for any given currency. In this case, as you can see in the data I am attaching, the largest timeseries would be that of the currency ETH.  Using the longest calendar as our first column I would then like to place the values described in item 3 above as rows in the new table.

[The new layout would look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rZym.png)

My steps to transform the raw data in the first table are [detailed in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecmL1.png)  Basically just expanding a JSON file and getting all the data I need into that first format which I described previously.

What I then do is:

1. Pivot using the first column
2. Transpose

That gives me a whole bunch of new columns.  Way more than I want.  Any idea what I can do differently?

Answer (score 0):

In powerquery,

1. click select **pair** column
2. Transform .. pivot column .. values column: **basis**  advanced options: do not aggregate

[image]

code:

```
    #"Pivoted Column6" = Table.Pivot(YourPriorStepName, List.Distinct(Source[pair]), "pair", "basis", List.Sum)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I am using your output image as a guide for the rest of this comment.  The problem I get is that each result in 'a' is "linked" to a specific timestamp.  Each result in 'b' is also linked to a specific timestamp.  So I end up getting two '3/4/2022 10:00:00 PM' rows and so on.  Any idea of how to sort that out?

Comment: Edit your question to post a real copy of your input data. Include the hidden columns or whatever shows in the real powerquery input and at least enough rows to have different pairs